# Redux: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm following this tutorial (https://www.udemy.com/course/mern-stack-front-to-back/) and build a mern website step by step. Everything went well until "Profile Reducer & Get Current Profile". I added `actions/profile.js` and `reducers/profile.js`, etc. And I got the following error.

I think my code is the same as what the video taught. Does anyone know what may be the problem?

[image]

reducers/profile.js:

```
import {
    GET_PROFILE,
    PROFILE_ERROR
  } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  profile: null,
  profiles: [],
  repos: [],
  loading: true,
  error: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case GET_PROFILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case PROFILE_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    default: 
      return state
  }
}
```

actions/profile.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import { setAlert } from "./alert";

import { GET_PROFILE, PROFILE_ERROR } from "./types";
import { response } from "express";

// Get current users profile
export const getCurrentProfile = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("/api/profile/me");

    dispatch({
      type: GET_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

Dashboard.js:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getCurrentProfile } from "../../actions/profile";

const Dashboard = ({ getCurrentProfile, auth, profile }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentProfile();
  }, []);

  return <div>Dashboard</div>;
};

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  getCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  profile: state.profile
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCurrentProfile })(Dashboard);
```

Comment: We don't know what code this course uses. Please paste the relevant content here so we can help debug the issue

Comment: Well, the project is quite big and has lots of files.

Comment: Okay but I hope you can appreciate the fact that we cannot help solve the issue by just guessing what the code looks like

Comment: Well, maybe some hint to debug? How do people often debug this kind of error?

Comment: Do you need `import { response } from "express";`? You don't appear to be using it in `actions/profile.js`. The stack trace appears to be throwing an error about from the `express` package. Have you tried debugging it step by step?

Comment: Indeed, deleting `import { response } from "express` solved the problem :-), thank you very much!

Comment: Could you add an answer so that I could accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the stack trace in your screenshot, the issue appears to be somewhere in relation to the `express` package.

From the code snippets you've submitted as part of the question, only the file: `actions/profile.js` contains any code in relation to `express`. It contains the following `import` statement:

```
import { response } from "express";
```

I don't see where you're using `response`, so I assume you don't need it - which is where you admitted the issue was coming from in the comments after you removed that line of code.